# How to access navigation prop in createStackNavigator component in react-native

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-mvc, react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack

I have a signing screen component which I want to show by default when user is not logged in. And after login I want to redirect to home page.
Below is the `createStackNavigator` setup:

```
const MainStack = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Home: { screen: TabStack },
    User: { screen: UserProfile },
    Login: {screen: SignIn },// Want to access navigation prop in this component
    Post: { screen: Post },
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'Login',
    mode: 'modal',
    headerMode: 'none'
  }
)
```

I am using Graphql and react-apollo in Main component **App.tsx**

```
class App extends React.Component<any,any> {
render() {

    return (<ApolloProvider client={client}>       
       <RootWithSession/>
    </ApolloProvider>)
  }
}
```

I want to access access navigation prop in `SignIn` component how to do that?

Comment: You need to have a parent component to store the state for you. Pass a handleLogin prop from the parent to the login sceen (child component). 

When the user logs in call this.props.handleLogin which will update the isLoggedin Prop in the parent component. When rendering you can check if isLoggedin is true or not.

Comment: @GregM My issue is with navigation prop. How can I redirect to home page when I don't have navigation prop in my Signin Component.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer, you can't access navigation prop in createStackNavigator. There are 2 ways

1. You can upgrade to [react-navigation-v5](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/hello-react-navigation) as the api is much better and you will access to props or state while building a navigator.
2. Add some logic inside `SignIn` component to navigate to `HomePage` or something

Comment: I could use react navigation v5 but not sure how to integrate it with `react-apollo`

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get access to Navigation object by create two separate nav stacks. One for signed in routes and other for login route as below:

```
const MainStack = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Home: { screen: TabStack },
    User: { screen: UserProfile },
    Comments: { screen: Comments },
    Post: { screen: Post }
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'Home',
    mode: 'modal',
    headerMode: 'none'
  }
)

const LoginStack = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Auth: { screen: SignIn }
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'Auth',
    mode: 'modal',
    headerMode: 'none'
  }
)

const AppContainer = createAppContainer(MainStack);
const LoginContainer = createAppContainer(LoginStack);
```

And in render method I used `screenProps` to provide navigation prop:

```
render() {
    console.log(this.state.userId)
    return (this.state.isLoggedIn?(<ApolloProvider client={client}>
      <AppContainer screenProps={{client,onLogout:this.onLogOut,loginId:this.state.userId}}/>
    </ApolloProvider>)
    :(
      <ApolloProvider client={client}>
        <LoginContainer screenProps={{client,onLogin:this.onLogin,loginId:this.state.userId}} />
      </ApolloProvider>
    ))
  }
```